# JQuery $.get() statement have security holes?

Tags: ajax, security

So I am making a script that allows a user to register and sign up for my website. The information is collected from an HTML form that simply asks for the username and password. Here's a dumbed down version of what I'm doing.

```
<form name="registration" id="registration" method="post" action="register.php">
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <input type="password" id="password">
    <input type="button" id="sendinfo">
</form>
```

I am wanting to use AJAX with JQuery to gather the data from the form and put it in a database so that the user doesn't have to be taken off of the page when they register. So I'm doing something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(e){

        var user = $("#username").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();

        $("#sendinfo").click(function(){

            //Send data to php file                 
            $.get("register.php?", {uname: user, pass: pass}, function (msg, status, xhr){
                alert(msg);
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

Will sending the password to "register.php" open me up to a security whole?

Comment: You should drop `?` from `register.php?`, it's unnecessary :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using POST instead of GET. GET parameters will show up in your server logs. You do not want that. Also, consider HTTPS to encrypt the data between the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) to avoid the security problem. This way the communication between the client and the server is encrypted using a certificate and a [man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) won't be able to read the traffic data.

Answer (score 0):

Not more than a normal submit would. You can enhance the security by adding SSL, to encrypt the data while sending it. Also if you are using a simple hashing algorithm for storing the password (like MD5 or SHA1), you could hash the password with Javascript before sending it.